# What does "sleep through an earthquake" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I heard this phrase recently in a podcast. I am not sure If I heard it right, but I couldn't find its meaning.

Here is the exact sentence I heard,

> She can sleep through an earthquake.

My assumption is that `she can sleep even with disturbing noise around`.

Please clarify.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. What made you doubt it? If you made sense of this on the first try, I would say you now, officially,  _**⚡️Speak English!⚡️**_. Congratulations! 

Comment: I thought *sleep through an earthquake* is an idiom but didn't find it when I googled.

Comment: It's not an idiom, no. It may be literal. Earthquakes don't necessarily make a lot of noise (not that I'm an expert), but they do cause a lot of motion. Some context would be helpful to answer the question more completely.

Comment: @Catija I heartily agree that more context will improve the question, but don't you think the OP here shows signs of "getting it"? I don't give away champagne bottle emojis lightly! (And it is extremely unlikely that the OP overheard a description of someone who actually slept through an earthquake. It's a figure of speech that certainly verges on idiom. In that regard, the OP's failure to find an idiom using these words through a Google search demonstrates the fallaciousness of the belief that "googling" is a useful exercise when it comes to learning English.)